# Add value of two cloumn in one using ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I Have a very simple question regarding SSRS, I also tryied many ways but not getting correct value
:
Example:Say i have report and i have to add first three column into last column as

```
column1   Column2  Column3 Total 
2        4          6        12
1        2          3         6
```

I tried to add this logic in my expression code as :

```
=Sum(Fields!Column1.Value, "DataSet1")+Sum(Fields!Column2.Value, "DataSet1")+Sum   (Fields!Column3.Value, "DataSet1")
```

But this is not working and returning #ERROR in last column , can you please suggest the correct way to add the column values into one column.

Answer (score 1):

Try Removing SUM() function because this is an aggregate function

```
Fields!Column1.Value + Fields!Column2.Value + Fields!Column3.Value
```

or just change your sql query to something like

```
select Column1, Column2, Column3, Column1 + Column2 + Column3 Total
from [your Table]
[where id = ???]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :But i have to use SUM() because I am using DataSet and i have implemented other rules on othrs columns as well.

Comment: Your code seems to be the sum of 3 columns to be put in the fourth col, so aggregate function won't work here unless you do have grouping..

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the combination of the textboxes instead of the sum of the fields?

```
ReportItems!textbox1.value+ReportItems!textbox2.value+ReportItems!textbox3.value
```